# Using Discriminant to find equation of a line?

Tags: derivatives, quadratics

Find the equation of the tangent to the parabola $$y = x^2 − 5x − 3$$ that is parallel to the line $3x − y − 7 = 0$.

I know how to solve this question utilizing differentiation, but I can't think of a way to solve it using quadratic discriminant theory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second equation in the question can be rearranged to:
$$ y = 3x - 7 $$
Now the $-7$ is irrelevant, as we are only interested in the slope which is $3$.
So let
$$ y = 3x + c  \tag{1}$$
be the form of the answer that we want. We need to find a value of $c$ that is a tangent. Now solve this equation and the quadratic given in the question as simultaneous equations:
$$ x^2 -5x -3 = 3x +c $$
When simplified and arranged in standard form is:
$$ x^2 -8x - (c+3) = 0 $$
Now letting **the discriminant** of the above equation equal $0$, because a tangent has only one intersection to the parabola, we have:
$$ b^2 - 4ac = 0 $$
Substitute the values into the discriminant equation we get:
$$ (-8)^2 -4 \times1 \times-(c+3) =0 $$
Solving this equation we find that:
$$ c = -19 $$
Now substitute this value for $c$ into the original straight line that we took from the question, I have labeled it ($1$) above. We get:
$$ y = 3x -19 $$
Or rearranging to standard from:
$$ 3x - y -19 = 0 $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You want to solve an equation which has a repeated root (that has something to do with the discriminant, right?). This equation is the intersection of the parabola and the line that has slop $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Given line $3x-y-7=0$

Required line is parallel to this line 
So we can take that as 
 $3x-y+k=0$----->(1)

Given parabola $y=x^2-5x-3$---->(2)

Solving (1)and(2)

$3x+k=x^2-5x-3$

$\implies x^2-8x-3-k=0$

Which is a quadratic equation in terms of x

If it's a tangent then it's discriminent is zero

$\Delta=0$

$(-8)^2-4(1)(-3-k)=0$

$implies 4k=-76$

$\implies k=-19$

Now required tangent is

$ 3x-y-19=0$